# how to setup pdo_sqlite and pdo module to work in php configuration

Tags: php, sql, pdo, cpanel

every time when a page of my site is loaded by someone i got these error in my error log file

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'PDO' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_sqlite' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so:
```

how to resolve this error please help me 
i dont know how to access these file etc

Comment: Look through your php.ini, and if you have a directory like `/etc/php.d/*.ini`. It is probably as simple as having two lines like `extension=pdo.so` and `extension=pdo.sqlite.so`  Possibly one in the main php.ini while another pair is in an extension-specific .ini file.

Comment: i tried but php.ini file not found

Comment: Check the output from `phpinfo()` or if you have shell access, from `php -i` to find the path of your system's php.ini file(s).

Answer (score 0):

You are using cPanel control panel so you need to check **/usr/local/lib/php.ini** file on your server.